# How to fix RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Question.date_time received a naive datetime?

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, python-datetime, django-timezone

I want to delete 60 seconds old records but I am getting this error

RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Question.date_time received a naive datetime (2022-08-27 16:09:30.659947) while time zone support is active.

```
def delete(self,request):
    expiry_date_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=60)
    print('Expiry time = ',expiry_date_time)
    count = Question.objects.filter(date_time__gte = expiry_date_time).delete()
    User.objects.all().update(total_question_added=0)
    resp = {'resp' : 'All questions deleted.','Total question deleted':len(count)}
    return Response(resp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**`timezone.now()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) instead, this will add the timezone to the timestamp:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.utils.timezone import now

# …

def delete(self, request):
    expiry_date_time = now() - timedelta(seconds=60)
    count, __ = Question.objects.filter(date_time__gte=expiry_date_time).delete()
    User.objects.update(total_question_added=0)
    return JsonResponse(
        {'resp': 'All questions deleted.', 'Total question deleted': count}
    )
```